# Grid width is not 960px

Tags: susy-compass

I might be missing something basic, but why susy grid does not amount to 960px?

```
$total-columns  : 12;             // a 12-column grid
$column-width   : 60px;            // each column is 4em wide
$gutter-width   : 10px;            // 1em gutters between columns
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width;  // grid-padding equal to gutters

$container-style: static;

.susy-container {
   @include container;
}
```

And I get the width 830px. Any idea why it's not 960px like other grids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try your math again:

```
(12*60) + (11*10) = 830
```

The official 960 Grid System uses `20px` gutters, and `10px` grid-padding:

```
$total-columns  : 12;
$column-width   : 60px;
$gutter-width   : 20px;
$grid-padding   : 10px;
```

That should give you what you are looking for.

```
(12*60) + (11*20) + (2*10) = 960
```

Comment: Could you also post the values for em? that would be great

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Do you want `960px` defined in `em`s? That depends entirely on your font size, and from there it's pretty basic math.

Comment: Thanks, I found http://pxtoem.com/ and that the main font size is 16px. From there it is basic math.